# how can i display json parse data in android alert dialog box?

Tags: android, json, android-alertdialog

I have to display the java script object notation parse data into the alert dialog box of an android. Is it possible? If we see the play store app and if we want to buy or subscribe some movie, then it shows the alert dialog, along with the movie banner thumbnail, movie name, its price and the continue button. Further if you click on continue button another dialog box is open. So anyone can help me, how to create it? This is the sample image of play store. I want to create this type of dialog in my application. Kindly suggest me weather it is possible or not. [image]

Here is the Code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.cartBookDescription);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          inputDialog()
        }
    });

 void inputDialog() {


    try {


       textView.setText("my order");
       dbhelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View alertDialog = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setView(alertDialog);



    alert.setTitle("Order Now");

    alert.setCancelable(false);
  alert.setView(edtQuantity);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Subscribe Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            int quantity = 0;


         } else {
                dialog.cancel();
          }
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
public void parseJSONData() {

    try {
        // request data from menu detail API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout((HttpParams) client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout((HttpParams) client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuDetailAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("Book"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);


            Detail_id = object.getString("id");
            Detail_audio = object.getString("audiofile");
            Detail_bookauthor = object.getString("bookauthor");
            Detail_image = object.getString("photo");
            Detail_name = object.getString("bookname");
            Detail_category = object.getString("bookcategory");
            Detail_premium = object.getString("premiumtype");
            Detail_price = Double.valueOf(formatData.format(object.getDouble("price")));
            Detail_validity = Integer.valueOf((object.getInt("validity")));             
            Detail_description = object.getString("description");

        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

parseJson method is written under asyncTask. Json data is parsing properly but when I am trying to show that data in the alert dialog, the alert dialog gets crashed.

Comment: Have you tried something? Any Idea?

Comment: yes i have created an xml layout file and inflated in the alert dialog box. But i want to show the json data in it. The layout contains one imageview and two textview

Comment: @xAqweRx Any Help?

Comment: provide your code. This will help to other understand what you want. Other way - answer will be generic - parse JSON and paste it to alert dialog using inflated custom view

Comment: @xAqweRx i have provided the code. This much code is enough or should i  add some more.

Comment: Solution depends on how you want to render the view. You want to get the json first and open the dialog or open dialog and get the json

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You just need to parse the data and create a custom dialog by creating an activity and a layout class. Example can be seen [here](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: it is only showing custom dialog. Kindly suggest me to show json data in it.

Comment: Have you succeeded to parse the data? If yes, then you can pass it via bundle. Here is the example http://android-coding.blogspot.co.id/2012/05/custom-dialog-with-data-passed-in.html.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create xml file for custom view and the add what you want to show in alert dialog as per your requirment refer this link [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)
or
https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/create-custom-alert-dialog-in-android/08/20/2015

Comment: i have already created a custom view, now want to show the data in alert dialog. How to show it?

Comment: post your json for better understand